# I can't add my highcharts graphic to the printJS

Tags: angular, highcharts, highcharts-ng, printjs, angular-highcharts

*I've an Angular app and using printJS in somewhere in my app.
There is a highcharts-chart at the top of the page and a gridTable at the bottom. I can print gridTable with printJS, but I want to print highcharts-chart together with gridTable.
Is it possible? If there any way to do it, how can i do?*

**Update - > Solved with different way. Dont need anything to do.**

Comment: Have u tried it and what's the result.  Does 'highcharts' special compare to other elements?

Comment: I can add field for datas in printJS function. But these data types are JSON, PDF etc. I haven't come across an example where a graph-like structure is added directly. Maybe printJS only handles files of this type, I don't know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I solved this with different way. Don't need anything to do.